# register form that auto login on previous user

Tags: php, sql

I have created a register form, that puts users in the database and auto loging in them directly after registration ( or it suppose to )

The problem is that when they register an account the autologin is redirecting the previous user that registerd.

I think its because the previous user is already loged id.. But if no one is logd in I get one of my own error message that says " The user dont exist"

Cant really figure out whats the problem.

Any ideas ?

This is some of my code.

```
if(empty($errors)){
                add_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
                $_SESSION['uid'] = fetch_user_id($_SESSION['username']);
                $_SESSION['username'] = htmlentities($_POST['username']);

                header("Location: profile.php?uid=" . $_SESSION['uid']);

                die();
```

And my function

```
//fetches profile information for the given user
function fetch_user_info($uid){
    $uid = (int)$uid;

        $sql = "SELECT
        `user_name` AS `username`,
        `user_email` AS `email`
    FROM `users`
    WHERE `user_id` = {$uid} ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = fetch_user_id($_POST['username']);
```

instead of:

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = fetch_user_id($_SESSION['username']);
```

Comment: If I use _POST instead of SESSION, it wont work at all. only get that the user dotn exist

Comment: @FelipeOtarola, if you switch to `$_POST['username']` and it can't find the user, then you either have a problem with `fetch_user_id()` or with `add_user()`. I'd guess it's likely the latter.

Comment: Hey!! you hade right, I was changen another query. When I changed
$_SESSION['uid'] = fetch_user_id($_SESSION['username']); to
 $_SESSION['uid'] = fetch_user_id($_SESSION['username']);

I started to work :)

Thanks alot